# How many characters is Google Adsense Publisher ID?

Tags: adsense

Google Adsense Publisher ID is how many characters. When I look at the publisher IDs I have, I see a total of 16 characters.

Is there a google publisher ID longer than 16 characters?

**pub-** next numbers **16 characters**. Does it have a longer publisher ID?

```
pub-3358186650566504
pub-3685135352464177
pub-7104543801500968
pub-5610649146674306
pub-6042571565839072
pub-3268638132077067
pub-9328633604439863
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [AdSense Help](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2923881?hl=en), they don't explicitly mention that the ids have exactly 16 digits.

But they seem to do at least for now.

> Your publisher ID looks like this: pub-1234567891234567.

The id looks long enough to me but you may want to be cautious and expect more digits.